# How can I get lightdm to start xmonad?

Tags: nixos, lightdm, xmonad

I've been running nixos with xmonad and using `startx` to start the xserver.  However I decided I would like to have a greeter.

I first tried sddm by disabling `startx` and enabling `sddm`

```
services.xserver {
  displayManager {
    startx.enable = false;
    sddm.enable = true;
  };
};
```

I rebuilt nixos (`nixos-rebuild switch`) and the sddm appeared to work fine but when I entered my password correctly nothing happened.  So being lazy and not commited to sddm, I decided rather than try and fix the issue I would just switch to another display manager, so I switched to lightdm

```
services.xserver {
  displayManager {
    startx.enable = false;
    lightdm.enable = true;
  };
};
```

And when I rebuilt a similar thing happened, lightdm starts fine but when I tried to log in it informs me "failed to login".  So I checked the logs in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`.

The log is fairly long so here is a selection after I logged on

```
[+15.51s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user ww: Success
[+15.51s] DEBUG: User ww authorized
[+15.51s] DEBUG: Greeter requests default session
[+15.56s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Failed to find session configuration default
[+15.56s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't find session 'default'
[+31.69s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+68.26s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 2
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Got signal 15 from process 1
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Caught Terminated signal, shutting down
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 997
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+701.81s] DEBUG: Terminating login1 session c1
[+701.87s] DEBUG: Session pid=1043: Sending SIGTERM
[+701.87s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
[+701.87s] WARNING: Session pid=1061: Error writing to session: Broken pipe
```

So it looks like it cant' find the "default session". And after looking around a bit I create `/usr/share/sessions/xmonad.desktop` with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=xmonad
Comment=This session starts xmonad
Exec=/home/ww/.local/bin/xmonad
Type=Application
```

Based on [the xmonad faq](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#How_can_I_use_xmonad_with_a_display_manager.3F_.28xdm.2C_kdm.2C_gdm.29). To reference this file I also create `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` with the contents:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xmonad
```

Based on [the lightdm page from the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM).

However on reboot this does not solve the problem or meaningfully change the error logs.

How can I bridge the gap so that lightdm will start xmonad properly?  I feel that I have a conceptual failing in understanding what is currently going on and what should be going on.

Comment: For sddm you just need a ~/.xsession file with a list of programs you want started when starting the x session.

Answer (score 1):

I am using XMonad with LightDM. Here is the relevant bit of my configuration.nix:

```
  services.xserver = {
    enable = true;
    windowManager = {
      default = "xmonad";
      xmonad = {
        enable = true;
        enableContribAndExtras = true;
      };
    };
    # On nixos-unstable I needed to add this deprecated setting (not sure if still needed)
    desktopManager.default = "none";
  };
```

I also have symlinked my `.xsession` to `.xinitrc` so my sessions started via {X,Light,G}DM would start the same programs.

```
ln -s .xinitrc .xsession
```